# Assets not loading on a subdomain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, subdomain, asset-pipeline

I have a subdomain setup in my `routes.rb` as follows:

```
  scope constraints: { subdomain: 'advertiser' } do
    root to: 'static#sub_index'
  end
```

When I navigate to this page I get 404 errors for all of my javascript and css assets including the built in defaults.

```
GET http://advertiser.subdomtest.dev/assets/application.css?body=1  advertiser.subdomtest.dev:5
GET http://advertiser.subdomtest.dev/assets/static.css?body=1  advertiser.subdomtest.dev:6
GET http://advertiser.subdomtest.dev/assets/jquery.js?body=1  advertiser.subdomtest.dev:7
GET http://advertiser.subdomtest.dev/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1  advertiser.subdomtest.dev:7
GET http://advertiser.subdomtest.dev/assets/turbolinks.js?body=1  advertiser.subdomtest.dev:7
GET http://advertiser.subdomtest.dev/assets/static.js?body=1  advertiser.subdomtest.dev:7
GET http://advertiser.subdomtest.dev/assets/application.js?body=1  advertiser.subdomtest.dev:7
```

I have tried making a new application and can reproduce this consistently so I must have something set up wrong.

Either I need to make the assets be requested from http://subdomtest.dev/assets or I need to make the subdomain also serve up the assets. How should I fix this?